# Search Multiple Channel Fields From One Low Search Field

Tags: low-search

Is it possible to have a single Low Search form doing something like:

> Low Search Form field called `name` which checks for values in channel fields called `company_name`, `first_name`, `last_name`
>   Low Search Form field called `keywords` which works just like the regular keywords field on Low Search

I know we could have three fields on the form to handle company name, first name, last name but we are trying to simplify it for users and just have one field called name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search multiple fields with one input field, you'll need to use the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords). The [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search) will always target a single field. Therefore, if you want to search for name only across 3 different fields, you'd need to create a collection where you give weight to the `company_name`, `first_name` and `last_name` fields only. You could use a `<select>` or radio buttons to let the user select the collection to use. For example:

```
Search for <input type="search" name="keywords">
in <select name="collection">
    <option value="">the whole site</option>
    <option value="names">names</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Go</button>
```

...where `names` is the collection for the name only. By leaving the `collection` parameter empty, you're telling Low Search to search *all* collections.